# Installing package attempts to download files for another non-dependent package

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I have been instructed to install a package called DART, by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libdart5-dev
```

This gives me several error messages, which all look like the following:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/ trusty/main libavresample1 amd64 7:1.2.6-1~trusty1
404  Not Found
```

However, after speaking to the author of DART, apparently the `libdart5-dev` package does not have a dependency on the `ffmpeg` package.

So why is `apt-get` trying to download files for `ffmeg`?

How should I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some of your external repositories (in details, this  `jon-severinsson/ffmpeg`) are not available for your Ubuntu version (it's [written in capital letters to "NOT USE" it](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+ppa-packages)).

You have to remove it from **Software & Updates** > **<kbd>Other Software</kbd>**.

It is better to not abuse with external repositories, each of them adds a potential security and stability problem to your system.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix it. Could you explain a couple of other things please? Firstly, why did installing DART even try to access the `jon-severinsson/ffmpeg` repository in the first place, when this is not a dependent package? And secondly, how can you determine whether a repository is available for your Ubuntu version (as you mentioned)? Thanks.

Comment: 1. I have no sure idea, since also `libdart5-dev` does not come from the standard repositories. The only one who can answer your question is the mantainer of the repository you are using. My guess is that it depends on something that on your system is provided by an external repository and this version depends on `libavresample1`. 2. Before adding it, you should look at its homepage and see if it is available or not.